# Window.angular.bootstrap-Warning Treid to load angular more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower

Developing one app using angularjs and everything is working fine after loading any web page but there is an message coming on the console

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

I checked it by opening the anguar.js file and found this

```
if (window.angular.bootstrap) {
  //AngularJS is already loaded, so we can return here...
  if (window.console) {
    console.log('WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.');
  }
```

One thing I need to mentioned here is that I have created one run and printing some text on the console to check at how many times the app.js has been called. I found the print on the console three time.
I also searched on google and found few suggestion like duplicate angular.js file declared in index.html or templateUrl not set properly but in my case I have checked and everything looks fine.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>ER4U</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!--base css styles-->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

<!--flaty css styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaty.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/treeDemo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-design.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaty-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.html">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-tree-filter-master/demo/demo.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/ui-utils-bower-highlight/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->

<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ui-tree.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload-master/dist/angular-file-upload.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-material/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker/dist/datetime-picker.min.js"></script>

 <script src="bower_components/angular-material/underscore-min.js"></script>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>



<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-tree-filter-master/demo/dist/angular-ui-tree-filter.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.js"></script> --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-tree-control/angular-tree-control.js"></script>

<script src="app/bower_components/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
<script src="app/bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.js"></script>

<!-- link for CSS when using the tree as a Dom element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="bower_components/angular-tree-control/css/tree-control.css"/>
<!-- link for CSS when using the tree as an attribute -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="bower_components/angular-tree-control/css/tree-control-attribute.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css"
    type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.css"
    type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css"/>


<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="ImportExport.js"></script>

<script src="common/ajax/ajax.service.js"></script>
<script src="common/ajax/confirm.directive.js"></script>
<script src="common/ajax/popup.directive.js"></script>

<!-- logout -->
<script src="header/header.controller.js"></script>
<script src="header/header.service.js"></script>
<!-- logout -->

<script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
<script src="menu/menu.controller.js"></script>
<script src="menu/menu.service.js"></script>
<script src="menu/menu.directive.js"></script>

<script src="user/user.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/user.service.js"></script>

<script src="purchase/purchase.controller.js"></script>
<script src="purchase/purchase.service.js"></script>
<script src="purchase/purchase.node.service.js"></script>
<script src="purchase/purchase.search.js"></script>

<script src="supplier/supplier.controller.js"></script>
<script src="supplier/supplier.service.js"></script>

<script src="tax/tax.controller.js"></script>
<script src="tax/tax.service.js"></script>

<script src="unit/unit.controller.js"></script>
<script src="unit/unit.service.js"></script>

<script src="firm/firm.controller.js"></script>
<script src="firm/firm.service.js"></script>

<script src="genericForm/genericForm.controller.js"></script>
<script src="genericForm/genericForm.service.js"></script>

<script src="store/store.controller.js"></script>
<script src="store/store.service.js"></script>

<script src="userType/userType.controller.js"></script>
<script src="userType/userType.service.js"></script>

<script src="brand/brand.controller.js"></script>
<script src="brand/brand.service.js"></script>

<script src="param/param.controller.js"></script>
<script src="param/param.service.js"></script>

<script src="category/category.controller.js"></script>
<script src="category/category.service.js"></script>

<script src="scheme/scheme.controller.js"></script>
<script src="scheme/scheme.service.js"></script>

<script src="attribute/attribute.controller.js"></script>
<script src="attribute/attribute.service.js"></script>

<script src="cashHead/cashHead.controller.js"></script>
<script src="cashHead/cashHead.service.js"></script>

<script src="subhead/subhead.controller.js"></script>
<script src="subhead/subhead.service.js"></script>

<script src="cashEntry/cashEntry.controller.js"></script>
<script src="cashEntry/cashEntry.service.js"></script>

<script src="priceEncode/priceEncode.controller.js"></script>
<script src="priceEncode/priceEncode.service.js"></script>

<script src="rackMaster/rackMaster.controller.js"></script>
<script src="rackMaster/rackMaster.service.js"></script>

<script src="rowMaster/rowMaster.controller.js"></script>
<script src="rowMaster/rowMaster.service.js"></script>

<script src="rackBox/rackBox.controller.js"></script>
<script src="rackBox/rackBox.service.js"></script>

<script src="sale/newSale.controller.js"></script>
<script src="sale/newSale.service.js"></script>

<script src="manageScreen/manageScreen.controller.js"></script>
<script src="manageScreen/manageScreen.service.js"></script>

<script src="barcodeMaster/barcode.controller.js"></script>
<script src="barcodeMaster/barcode.service.js"></script>


<script src="counter/counter.controller.js"></script>
<script src="counter/counter.service.js"></script>

<script src="broker/broker.controller.js"></script>
<script src="broker/broker.service.js"></script>

<script src="document/document.controller.js"></script>
<script src="document/document.service.js"></script>

<script src="upload/upload.controller.js"></script>
<script src="upload/upload.service.js"></script>
<script src="upload/upload.directive.js"></script>
<script src="upload/up.controller.js"></script>

<script src="customer/customer.controller.js"></script>
<script src="customer/customer.service.js"></script>

<script src="category_attribute/category_attribute.controller.js"></script>
<script src="category_attribute/category_attribute.service.js"></script>

<script src="menuaccess/menuaccess.controller.js"></script>
<script src="menuaccess/menuaccess.service.js"></script>

<script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="login/login.service.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--basic scripts-->
<!-- <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<!--page specific plugin scripts-->
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
<script src="assets/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<!--flaty scripts-->
<script src="js/flaty.js"></script>
<script src="js/flaty-demo-codes.js"></script>


<style>
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style> 

</head>
<body>
<!-- sppinner -->
    <div ng-app="er4u">
            <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" spinner-key="spinner-1" ></span> 
            <div ui-view="header"></div>
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading AngularJS twice into your page. Remove one resource include and you will be fine.

1) Near `html5-boilerplate`

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

2) Near `angular-material`

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks alot, its worked but my run method inside app.js is executing three times. Can you please help me on this as well.

Comment: Glad to help ya! Please create a new question about that new problem while this question is solved.

Comment: @VaibhavDalela I see you asked a lot of questions right now without marking right answers. It would be glad if you mark the right answer. It will help other users to solve problems and its how stackoverflow works.